# UNIX Script - Coloring HTML content based on current date

Tags: html, bash, unix

I want to write a script which will colour lines of the input green if they represent the current date (i.e. on 2017-07-13, the second line should be green), red otherwise.

Input format (CSV):

```
Feed1,2017-07-01
Feed2,2017-07-13
Feed3,2017-07-03
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
while IFS="," read dtts feed; do
  if [ "$dtts" == "$DATEVALID" ]; then
    echo "<tr>"
    echo "<td><font color=green>$dtts</font></td>"
    echo "<td bgcolor=green>$feed</td>"
    echo "</tr>"
  else
    echo "<tr>"
    echo "<td><font color=red>$dtts</font></td>"
    echo "<td bgcolor=red>$feed</td>"
    echo "</tr>"
  fi
done < $INPUTFILE.csv
```

But it is showing incorrect output (all lines have the same colour).

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: while IFS="," read dtts feed
do
if [ "$dtts" == "$DATEVALID" ]
then
echo "<tr>"
echo "<td><font color=green>$dtts</font></td>"
echo "<td bgcolor=green>$feed</td>"
echo "</tr>"
else
echo "<tr>"
echo "<td><font color=red>$dtts</font></td>"
echo "<td bgcolor=red>$feed</td>"
echo "</tr>"
fi
done < $OUTPUTFILE.csv

Comment: Hi, while putting my issue I have found why it is not working, I am mapping incorrect field to the condition hence not working.

Comment: Yes, that is what our answers say …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of possible problems with your code. Some have been fixed when editing your original question, please consider formatting your code properly when asking a question on SO.

You are reading fields from the CSV in the incorrect order.

```
read dtts feed # This means the first field is $dtts, the second is $feed
```

So the while loop should probably look like

```
while IFS="," read feed dtts; do
```

And finally, you did not provide the code responsible for `$DATEVALID` or `$INPUTFILE`. An important question is whether `$DATEVALID` is in the same format as the one used in your input file. To obtain such date within a shell script, you could try:

```
DATEVALID=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
```

This should give you today's date in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format you need. To summarise:

```
DATEVALID=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
INPUTFILE="input.csv"
while IFS="," read feed dtts; do
  echo "<tr>"
  if [ "$dtts" == "$DATEVALID" ]; then
    echo "<td><font color=green>$dtts</font></td>"
    echo "<td bgcolor=green>$feed</td>"
  else
    echo "<td><font color=red>$dtts</font></td>"
    echo "<td bgcolor=red>$feed</td>"
  fi
  echo "</tr>"
done < $INPUTFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem -- your data does not match the variables you are specifying in your `read` command.

First question -- what is the value of `$DATEVALID` ?

`echo`ing your variables will go a long way toward troubleshooting these types of problems.